# Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) monotonicity constraint

Tags: r, time-series, data-science, data-analysis, dtw

How to specify a monotonicity constraint (that one time series should not come before the other) when using dynamic time warping?

For example, I have cost and revenue data; one should impact the other but not vice versa. I am using the basic **dtw** package but I know that there are many others that could be better. Below is my current alignment.

(I would like to save the corresponding revenue point into a separate column, would that be possible?)

```
library(dtw)

asy<-dtw(df$cost,
         df$revenue,
         keep=TRUE,       
         window.size = 7, # max 7 days shift
         step=asymmetric  # gives best results for this problem (other: symmetric1 & symmetric2)
         );

plot(asy, type="two", off=1);
```

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can enforce this by defining your own window function.
For example, take these series:

```
library(dtw)

set.seed(310L)

idx <- seq(0, 6.28, len = 100L)
reference <- sin(idx)
query <- cos(idx) + runif(100L) / 10

foo <- dtw(query, reference, keep = TRUE, step.pattern = symmetric2, window.type = sakoeChibaWindow, window.size = 30L)
plot(foo, type = "two", off = 2)
```

[image: before]

The red line is the reference,
and you want the query's values to only match values from the past or the same day.

```
win_fun <- function(i, j, ...) { i >= j }

bar <- dtw(query, reference, keep = TRUE, step.pattern = symmetric2, window.type = win_fun)
plot(bar, type = "two", off = 2)
```

[image: after]

If you want to match past values strictly excluding values from the same time,
change the condition to `i > j`.

Check the documentation of `dtwWindowingFunctions` for more options.
You might want to add a window size constraint.